# Event doesnt work for elements putted via Ajax

Tags: javascript

I have got some elements with event "onclick", but i need to update this elements with ajax, unfortunately the onclick event is already bound.

My question is, how to refresh the event trigger? Is there way to do it?

Comment: Use delegate events like 'on' , 'delegate' ,etc look at this https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Can you show us your code to look at?

Comment: When you used addEventlistener then this is worth reading: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp for onclick-property just assign null to it.

Comment: @Arun_SE: I don't see a `jquery` tag or any other evidence the OP is using jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: i like the word ajax

Comment: @Arun_SE: "Ajax" is a common term, doesn't mean the OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an event can only be bound to elements that exist at that time, you could use a little trick called "event delegation".

That means that you are going to listen for clicks on a parent element that already exists, and if the click was on a child that meets your requirement, do something. For example, your newly added elements could be appended to a container:

```
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Since you did not mention using jQuery, I made a version without it, and one with it. So for example:

---

**Native JS**

```
document.getElementById('output').addEventListener('click', makeMeRed);
```

Then, in the `makeMeRed` example function, you need to check if the element you clicked on (`event.target`) meets your requirements (I want an `<li>` in this case):

```
function makeMeRed(event){
    if(event.target && event.target.nodeName == 'LI'){
        event.target.style.background = 'red';
    }
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

---

**Using jQuery**

The event delegation can be this simple:

```
$('#output').on('click', 'li', makeMeRed);

function makeMeRed() {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score -1):

you can fire click event using this.

```
$( "class or id " ).trigger(click);
```